# Отключить оптимизацию при поиске файлов во время тестирования

Tags: c#

есть приложение которое ищет в директории файлы с определенным расширением и далее выполняет с ними некоторые действия.

```
var Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories); // берем файлы из директорий
```

---

```
foreach (var file in Files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                Tools.GetFileHeader(fi);
                ...// пока всё отключил выполняю только обработку заголовка
            }
```

в процессе тестирования различных алгоритмов для приложения по обработке файлов столкнулся с оптимизацией которая происходит на уровне ОС. 
Первый запуск приложения происходит за 503225 мс, дальнейшие запуски имеют время порядка 8573 мс, 8497 мс и тд.
Для эмуляции первого запуска ничего лучше чем ребут пока не придумал. Можно ли как-то программно этот кэш чистить, чтобы каждый запуск приложения был как первый?

ps На компе стоит SSD, размер файлов от 10 кб до 6000 кб. количество файлов ~150000 штук.

Comment: Нагуглил [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478340/clear-file-cache-to-repeat-performance-testing).

Comment: Да, RAMMap работает. Empty stanby list очищает cashe и можно эмулировать "холодный старт" приложения. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Хотелось бы знать что там происходит при нажатии на кнопку Empty stanby list. И можно ли подобное на c# реализовать.

Comment: Эм... там в комментах на ответ есть ссылка