# Многопоточность, асинхронность. Разница во времени выполнения?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, parallel

Я выполняю три метода, перечитываю текстовый файл, на предмет, кол-ва букв а в нём, я выполняю это тремя способами: 1 последовательно, асинхронно и многопоточно.
Вот результат:
Wasted the time consistently method 00:00:01.9155446

Wasted the time async method 00:00:00.7132119

Wasted the time multy Thread method 00:00:19.6830515

Подскажите почему последовательное выполнение быстрее всего, это же не логично, что тогда быстрее async or thread. И ещё вопрос что тогда такое Parallel.Onvoke() ? Если асинхронность понятно, это когда в методе есть async and await Многопоточность, это как я понял, если в методе создаётся thread(Method); thread.Start(); А вот эта параллельность это что? Чем отличается от многопоточности?

```
        public static int CountForThirdMethod { get; set; } = 0;
        static object locker = new object();

        private static int ReadFile(string path)
        {
            int count = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line = String.Empty;
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        i++;
                        MatchCollection matches3 = Regex.Matches(line, "а");
                        count += matches3.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine($"in line num {i} count symbol \"a\" equal: {matches3.Count}");
                    }
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        public static async Task<int> ReadFileAsync(string path)
        {
            int count = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string line = String.Empty;
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        i++;
                        MatchCollection matches3 = Regex.Matches(line, "а");
                        count += matches3.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine($"in line num {i} count symbol a equal: {matches3.Count}");
                    }
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        public static int CountOfThreads { get; set; } = 0;

        public static void ReadFileThread(string path)
        {
            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path);
            string line = String.Empty;
            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WorkWithLines));
                    thread.Start(line);
                    threads.Add(thread);
                }
            }
            foreach (var thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Join();
            }
        }

        public static int Counter { get; set; } = 0;


        private static void WorkWithLines(object line)
        {
            Counter++;
            MatchCollection matches3 = Regex.Matches(line.ToString(), "а");
            Console.WriteLine($"in line num {Counter} count symbol a equal: {matches3.Count}");

            lock (locker)
            {
                CountForThirdMethod += matches3.Count;
            }

        }

        static void Extract(string whereFile, string nameOfFolder, string namOfFile)
        {
            string nameOfFolder1 = "Resources";
            string namOfFile1 = "text.txt";

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApp1" + "." + (nameOfFolder1 == "" ? "" : nameOfFolder1 + ".") + namOfFile1))
            {
                using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(whereFile + "\\" + namOfFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                            w.Write(r.ReadBytes((int)s.Length));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        static void PutFileInOutput()
        {
            Extract(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Resources", "text.txt");
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            PutFileInOutput();
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\text.txt";
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            Stopwatch stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();
            ReadFile(path);
            int count1 = ReadFile(path);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            stopwatch2.Start();
            int count2 = await ReadFileAsync(path);
            stopwatch2.Stop();


            stopwatch3.Start();

            ReadFileThread(path);
            int count3 = CountForThirdMethod;
            stopwatch3.Stop();


            Console.WriteLine($"Wasted the time consistently method {stopwatch.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Wasted the time async method {stopwatch2.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Wasted the time multy Thread method {stopwatch3.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Total count of \"a\" in consistently method: {count1 + Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Total count of \"a\" in async method: {count2 + Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Total count of \"a\" in multy Thread method: {count3 + Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Покажите код, без него темы для обсуждения нет.

Comment: Добавил код, но по сути, мне даже не столько важен мой код, сколько конкретная теория по этим понятия: что это такое, когда это используется и что из этого лучше? Я имею ввиду асинхронность, многопоточность и паралельность

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев замечу, что разницу между прогонами может давать оптимизация со стороны операционной системы. посмотрите вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072887/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Многопоточный код у тебя ужасный. Создание треда дорогая операция, а ты создаёшь на каждую строку. Более того, эти потоки будут сражаться за процессор, а переключение контекста тоже дорогая операция. Многопоточный код д.б. примерно такой: пул потоков по числу процессоров, файл читается посторочно, строки закидываются в очередь, потоки берут строки из очереди.

Comment: Ещё отмечу, что асинхронные операции нужны для параллельного исполнения, пока основной код продолжает работать над своей задачей. Если основной код тут же начинает ждать результат асинхронной операции, то ты просто платишь за создание асинхронной задачи (пусть и небольшую плату) и не получаешь никакой выгоды.

Answer (score 6):

Файл - это такая вещь, которая читается одним потоком (тут под потоком я подразумеваю Stream). То есть самое эффективное, что можно сделать - это читать файл порциями, с буфером, чем больше буфер и меньше чтений - тем лучше.

Ваш синхронный вариант просто читает файл без перерыва.

Ваш многопоточный вариант = это синхронный + вы создаете потоки (что является дорогой операцией) + вы потоки пытаетесь синхронизировать (что по сути тормозит выполнение). Потому этот ваш вариант медленней синхронного.

Ваш асинхронный вариант = это как синхронный + машина состояний. Потому этот вариант медленней, чем синхронный.

Таким образом, вы свой код могли даже не запускать, там и так ясно, кто быстрее обработает файл. Но сам пример не самый удачный. А теперь возьмите 300 жестких дисков и по 100 файлов на каждом и повторите эксперимент :)

В вашем случае узкое место - это файл, а не способ, как вы его обрабатываете.

Ещё чуть чуть [полезной инфы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1105232/179763).

Comment: лан, спасибо, чё накинуль-то.. ну тупой я, я ш учусь))

Comment: Так я только за, что вы учитесь. Я ад вон сколько текста для вас написал, а у меня, между прочем, русских букв на клавиатуре нет - страдаю на каждом слове :)

Comment: ничего себе, спасибо, может кто другой расскажет или вы на англ. Parallel.Invoke и Thread.Start() это же не одно и тоже? А в чём тогда разница, вроде и там и там всё выполняется одновременно, в асинк как я понял, даёшь данные другому потоку, когда он выполнит он мне перезвонит и я продолжу вычислять, а в Parallel.Invoke и Thread.Start() вроде как всё одновременно, в чём же разница?

Comment: `Thread.Start()` - это явный запуск потока. `Parallel.Invoke` - это просьба выполнить какие то задания по возможности параллельно. Как именно `Parallel.Invoke` будет выполнять задания - это уже его дела. Может создаст потоки, может испольщует пул потоков, а может и синхронно выполнит.